# cannot find module npm-cli.js

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, node-modules

I reinstalled npm several times and I can start npm succesfully by writing npm start. Unfortunately, when I deploy my code with docker (npm dockerDeploy) I found out the error below. I am using Npm v6.1.0.

Regards

```
 Error :  

 Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\kopuz\git\icon2\icon\daimler-icon-frontend\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:438:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:386:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
at startup (node.js:160:18)
at node.js:445:3
module.js:440
throw err;
 ^
```

Comment: Can you provide Dockerfile and the commands you are using to build and run the container.

Comment: Sure . The docker command that I used to deploy : .\gradlew --console plain dockerDeploy

Comment: To c lean and migrate db I use .\gradlew --console plain cleanAndMigrateDb